# global variables doesn't change value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, global-variables, hashchange

My project is composed by 2 html pages:

1. `index.html`, which contains the login and the registration form.
2. `user_logged.html`, which contains all the features of a logged-in user.

Now, what I want to do is a control if the user is really logged in, to avoid the case where a user paste a url in the browser and can see the pages of another user. 
hours as now, if a user paste this url in the browser:

```
 www.user_loggato.html?user=x#profile
```

is as if logged in as user x and this is not nice.

My html pages both use js files that contains scripts. 
I decided to create a global variable called logged inizialized to false and change the variable to true when the login is succesful.

The problem is that the variable, remains false.

here is the code:

```
 var logged=false; (write in the file a.js)
```

while in the file b.js I have:

```
 function login() {

 //if succesfull
        logged=true;
       window.location.href = "user_loggato.html?user="+ JSON.parse(str).username + #profilo";
```

Now with some alerts I found that my variable logged is always false. Why?

Comment: global does **not** mean that it will persist across several different pages. Once a page reloads all variables are lost, as HTML (and javascript) is stateless, unless you use a storage of some kind (read: cookies or localStorage).

Comment: Nothing you store on the browser will be safe from a user just switching their login status manually. You need to keep track of this on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is not the way to go, as it runs on the client side. Even if there would be a way to share javascript variables between different requests, the user could manipulate them.

You have to take a server side technique for this (maybe PHP with sessions).

Comment: ok, I don't use php, i'm using Java. If i create a coloumn in the database called logged and I change it every time It could be right?

Comment: @user1856906 Java has sessions as well.

Comment: This is not how sessions are meant to be used. If you save "loggedin" in the database, and the user turns off the pc, will he be logged in forever? Read a good tutorial on sessions and the usage with java.

Comment: no, in the login moment, if the login is successful I turn the logged attribute to true.

Comment: and when do you turn it off again?

Comment: ahhhh got it! It's not useful

Answer (score 0):

JS variables will reset on every submit/refresh. You could use sessionStorage or cookies for this purpose. For example:

Put this in your login form:

```
function login() {
    window.sessionStorage[logged] = true;
   window.location.href = "user_loggato.html?user="+ JSON.parse(str).username + #profilo";
}
```

And in your user_loggato.html, you can retrive it like:

```
function getLoginStatus() {
    return window.sessionStorage['logged'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that even if you do this, it's not safe.

Comment: I have to define the variable logged?

Comment: Agree with @Jon Dvorak, its not save. Better to do in server side.

Comment: You don't have to define a variable.